# Why CTAS query in hive doesn't give result as expected?

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata

Here is the case, I create a hive table "test" with 100 rows.

When I start hive terminal and input the following SQL

```
select * from test tablesample(2 percent);
```

it returns 3 lines of data;

But when I add "create table as Select" like below.

```
create table sample as select * from test tablesample(2 percent);
```

I found there are 100 rows in the table "sample".

I don't know why.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: hive version is 2.2.1

Answer (score 0):

The [Documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Sampling) says that `TABLESAMPLE (n PERCENT)`  will allow Hive to pick up **at least n% data size** (**notice it doesn't necessarily mean number of rows**) as inputs.  If we fail to sample it, the input of MapReduce job will be the whole table/partition. We do it in HDFS block level so that the **sampling granularity is block size**. For example, if block size is 256MB, even if n% of input size is only 100MB, you get 256MB of data.

**Unfortunately it does not guarantee to fetch each time the same blocks, total row_count can vary.**

I suggest to increase percent and add `limit n` to guarantee n rows returned. Or simply use `limit n`:

```
select * from test tablesample(5 percent) limit 100; --may perform faster
```

or

```
select * from test limit 100;
```

Limit of course performs less efficient than tablesample because limit works on reducer, maybe both tablesample and limit combined will allow acceptable performance.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explaination of tablesample. But why the tablesample got correct result, but not after add "create table as Select".

Comment: @Daniel Both of results are correct I guess, this is what I'm trying to tell. For some reason it reads different blocks of data. Maybe the changed execution plan affects it somehow. But actually tablesample does not guarantee to read the same blocks each time.

Comment: Thanks again!  Yes,  but can not explain that the table "test " has only one block. So I wonder if something wrong with "create table as" .